# ASP GridView and DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have an asp page with a GridView control.  One of the columns in the grid view is a dropdownlist.  the drop down list are filled using the RowDataBound event on the page load event.  However, one of the options in the list, when selected, will popup a dialog that will allow the user to add a new item to the list, and that newly added item becomes the selected item for that drop down.  This part I have working fine, but I want to be able to add the new item to the drop down list for every row in the grid.  How do I, in a way, re bind the drop down list in all rows after the page has loaded without having to loop through each field?

Comment: Are all the dropdown lists populated from a common, shared datasource?

Answer (score 0):

If all the DDL's have a shared DataSource then it should just be a matter of forcing a postback after adding the new listitem.  But how are you adding the new listitem?

If your popup is simply adding a new html `<option>` tag to an html `<select>` tag, this is not the same thing as updating the DDL DataSource.

For all the DDL's to show the new listitem your popup would have to perform a postback that updates the DDL datasource(s) and all the DDL controls in the GridView would need to be rebound.

This would happen automatically on a postback assuming that the DDL controls are connected to their datasource via the **`DataSourceID`** property.  If you are making use of the **`DataSource`** property then you will have to call **`DataBind()`** explicitly for each DDL control, which I think you said you are doing in the GridView **`RowDataBound`** event.

Alternatively you *could* loop through all your ddl controls clientside and add the same item to each control, but you would lose all those changes the next time the page refreshed and I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks.  I was able to add the new value to the shared data source, and all the list are updated on a Post Back.  To set that new value as the selected value of the particular drop down where it was added, I had to retain that value in a hidden field and could then access it after the Postback and Databind().